# Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln\sin^2(ax)}{\ln\sin^2(bx)}$ without using the L'Hopital's rule or Taylor's series

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

This limit is proposed to be solved without using the L'Hopital's rule or Taylor series:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\sin^2(ax)}{\ln\sin^2(bx)},
$$
where $a,b=const$. I know how to calculate this limit using the L'Hopital's rule:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\sin^2(ax)}{\ln\sin^2(bx)}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{2a\sin (ax)\cos (ax)}{\sin^2(ax)}}{\frac{2b\sin (bx)\cos (bx)}{\sin^2(bx)}}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{\sin (ax)\cos (ax)}{\sin (bx)\cos (bx)}\cdot\frac{\sin^2(bx)}{\sin^2(ax)}
$$
(using the asymptotic equivalence $\sin x\sim x$)
$$
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{ax}{bx}\cdot\frac{(bx)^2}{(ax)^2}=1,
$$
but I don't know to calculate this limit without derivatives.

Comment: Off-topic: when $x\to 0$ then $\cos(ax)=\cos(bx)=1$ and not $ax/bx$.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, I know. I mean $\sin (ax)\sim ax$, $\sin(bx)\sim bx$.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @user2661923 It is from one problem book in Russian

Comment: Hint: The numerator is $\approx 2\ln (ax)$, and similarly for the denominator.

Comment: The reason that I asked is that normally, for a problem with the constraints that you have given (i.e. no L'Hopital's rule or Taylor series), the book will first *prepare* the student before presenting the problem.  Typically, this preparation involves theorems, worked examples or previously solved problems.  The idea is that then, the posed problem represents an application of the already presented theory.  However, it is unclear what the phrase "*problem book*" signifies.  If the book is only a presentation of problems, with no build-up, then the situation clearly becomes *problematic*.

Comment: Re previous comment, *yes*, pun intended.

Comment: @user2661923 I agree with you completely. The problem is that this problem is given before the section with L'Hôpital's rule and, obviously, implies some other solution

Comment: My typical reaction here would be : [1] attack the problem with L'Hopital's rule [2] Scrutinize the proof of L'Hopital's rule, line by line [3] *Re-invent* *the wheel* by using the analysis embedded in the proof of L'Hopital's rule, and applying this analysis *from scratch* to the given problem.  This allows you to resolve the problem with all use of L'Hopital's rule eliminated.  My suspicion is that this is an **out-of-order** problem, that the problem composer intended that you struggle with.  ...see next comment

Comment: **Perhaps**, the idea is that you were supposed to inadvertently walk in the path of L'Hopital's rule, solving the problem from scratch.  This experience was then supposed to motivate you to appreciate the general utility of L'Hopital's rule and (in general) discourage you from *re-inventing* *the wheel*.  That is, you are then supposed to be motivated to try to solve problems by using recently presented theory.  Personally, I consider **out-of-order** problems a symptom that the author is in the *wrong line of work*.

Comment: The alternative explanation that (unfortunately) is often accurate is that the **out-of-order** problem was posed before L'Hopital's rule only because of the author's negligence.  The idea here is that rhe author intended that you use L'Hopital's rule to attack the problem.  Actually, on mathSE, I once criticized a math book for presenting an out-of-order problem.  A respondent defended the book by indicating that it was intended only for math graduate students, who are supposed to be able to find the needed theory to resolve out-of-order problems or unsupported assertions.

Comment: @Sebastiano I am not opposed to downvotes in general, but I think in that case I would be nice to explain the downvote (actually I did not downvote your answer)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Very kind Severin, no no. You have right to 100 %. I have deleted my ugly and erroneus answer. There was an abnormal mistake. I thank you very very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, $\sin^2(x)=\sin^2(-x)$, we can accept $a,b\in \mathbb R^{+}$. Thus we have,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\sin^2(ax)}{\ln\sin^2(bx)}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\ln|\sin(ax)|}{2\ln|\sin(bx)|}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln|\sin(ax)|}{\ln|\sin(bx)|}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\ln\sin(ax)}{\ln\sin(bx)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\left(\frac{\frac{\ln\sin(ax)}{\ln ax}}{\frac{\ln\sin(bx)}{\ln bx}}\times \frac{\ln ax}{\ln bx}\right)\\
&=1.\end{align}$$

---

**Explanation:**

Let $\alpha,\thinspace x\in\mathbb R^{+}$, then we can write the following limits:

1. $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\ln\sin(\alpha x)}{\ln\alpha x}=1$.

Use:

$\ln(\sin \alpha x) = \ln \alpha x + \ln\left(\frac {\sin \alpha x} {\alpha x}\right)$

2. $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\ln ax}{\ln bx}=1$

Use:

$\ln (\alpha x)=\ln \alpha+\ln x.$

Comment: Interesting approach, in that the result that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ can be interpreted as a consequence of applying the squeeze theorem against the axioms used to define the sine and cosine functions (re Tom Apostol's sine/cosine *axioms*).  This indicates that you are **not** (inadvertently) applying L'Hopital's rule.  Just out of curiosity, re the comments that I left following the question, is it your opinion that your approach may have been *intended* by the problem composer?

Comment: @user2661923 I fixed some of my mistakes.

Comment: @user2661923  I'm not sure about the answer to your question and I have **not** a good calculus experience. Please, feel free to show my mistakes.

Comment: You misread my comment.  I didn't scrutinize your answer that closely, because I have an aversion to this type of problem.  That is, it is problems like this that L'Hopital's rule  was designed for.  Anyway, I am unaware of any mistakes in your answer.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for reviewing my answer ( ◜‿◝ )

Answer (score 3):

Can someone tell me what is wrong in what I'm doing?
Assuming $ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(\alpha x\right)}{\alpha x}=1 $
$$ \require{cancel} \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(\sin^{2}\left(ax\right)\right)}{\ln\left(\sin^{2}\left(bx\right)\right)}=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\sin^{2}\left(ax\right)}{\left(ax\right)^{2}}\cdot\left(ax^{2}\right)\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{\sin^{2}\left(bx\right)}{\left(bx\right)^{2}}\cdot\left(bx^{2}\right)\right)}=\frac{\ln\left(\cancelto{1}{\frac{\sin^{2}\left(ax\right)}{\left(ax\right)^{2}}}\right)+\ln\left(\left(ax\right)^{2}\right)}{\ln\left(\cancelto{1}{\frac{\sin^{2}\left(bx\right)}{\left(bx\right)^{2}}}\right)+\ln\left(\left(bx\right)^{2}\right)}=\frac{\ln\left(1\right)+\ln\left(\left(ax\right)^{2}\right)}{\ln\left(1\right)+\ln\left(\left(bx\right)^{2}\right)}=\frac{\ln\left(\left(ax\right)^{2}\right)}{\ln\left(\left(bx\right)^{2}\right)}\Rightarrow \\
\frac{2\ln\left(ax\right)}{2\ln\left(bx\right)}=\frac{\ln\left(ax\right)}{\ln\left(bx\right)}=\frac{\ln\left(a\right)+\ln\left(x\right)}{\ln\left(b\right)+\ln\left(x\right)} $$
Dividing both sides by $\ln(x) $ will bring us to $ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(a\right)+\ln\left(x\right)}{\ln\left(b\right)+\ln\left(x\right)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\ln\left(a\right)}{\ln\left(x\right)}+\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{\ln\left(x\right)}}{\frac{\ln\left(b\right)}{\ln\left(x\right)}+\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{\ln\left(x\right)}}=\frac{0+1}{0+1}=1 $

Comment: You need to keep your limits. What is the computation in the very end?

Comment: Now that you figured it out, good work.  Thanks for the edit!

Comment: It's the mistake, i should have gotten $ \frac{\ln\left(ax\right)}{\ln\left(bx\right)} $

Comment: After the arrow it goes wrong try, $\frac{\ln(ax)^2)}{\ln(bx)^2}=\frac{\ln(a)+\ln (x)}{\ln(b)+\ln (x)}=\frac{\frac{\ln a}{\ln x}+1}{\frac{\ln b}{\ln x}+1}$,

Comment: Why do you think you can cancel $\frac{\sin^{2}\left(ax\right)}{\left(ax\right)^{2}}$ inside the logarithm? Does this follow from some theorem?

Comment: Using the known limit I presented above we get : $ \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\alpha x\right)}{\alpha x}\right)=1\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to0}\ln\left(\frac{\sin\left(ax\right)}{ax}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(ax\right)}{ax}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\ln\left(1\cdot1\right) $

Comment: @Danny Blozrov This is undeniable. The question is different: why it is possible to take a part of a function and replace it with the limit of this part. I was taught that, in general, this is wrong.

Comment: In general, it is wrong. It is allowed when composing a continuous function.(in this case $\lim_{x\to1}\ln\left(x\right)=0$ )
There are other conditions as well, but being continuous is enough.

Comment: @Danny Blozrov Could you provide a link to the theorem, please? I don't know such a rule

Comment: @Danny Blozrov I think you are wrong. We can't in the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\tan x}x-\frac{\sin x}x}{x^2}$ replace $\frac{\tan x}x$ or $\frac{\sin x}x$ with 1. This gives us some wrong result, although the identical function is continuous

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymYg0VQbwtY should suffice

Comment: @Danny Blozrov The theorem from the video applies to the function under the limit sign as a whole, and not to a separate part of it. I'm sorry, but I downvoted your answer because  I am convinced that it is wrong

Comment: fair enough, sorry for confusing you.